# Convert multiple text files to matrices R

Tags: r, file, matrix

I'm aware that there are a lot of similarly themed questions on Stackoverflow to this question but none of them really clarify the exact questions that I have:
I have a number of text files, the content of which are organised into a two columned matrix in each. I need to convert the file contents to matrices such that I can read them in a specific way.

```
      individualmatrices1<-system("ls /Users/Deirdreclarkson/rpractice/traj1*", intern=TRUE)
```

Now that I have created a list of the files containing their matrices I need to convert the actual content to actual, iterable matrices. My attempt is as follows:

```
     readTrajectory <- function(traj1) {
       a <- data.matrix(read.table(traj1, sep=" ", header=TRUE))
       return(a)
     }
     for (i in 1:length(individualmatrices1)){
       trajectorieslist <- readTrajectory(individualmatrices1[i])
     }
```

And now the final step of converting them each to matrices:

```
     matrices<-lapply(trajectorieslist, data.matrix)#is it necessary to account for headers?
```

However as you may have noticed in the previous code there are headings to each file content and I need to account for them somehow.

My question is: is it possible to convert files that are organised in a matrix fashion to actual matrices in R in an easier way than above? And when I have done this what should the argument of my final function be- myFunc(matrices), such that it will operate on one of the made matrices? Can I then just use a for loop(i in 100) or lapply to make the function operate on all of them?
Thanks